# Laravel Eloquent Query Multiple records based on set criteria

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a form where my users can set Criteria to search their customer database, however I am struggling to pull the query together for this (working in Laravel 5.7).

Currently the criteria customers can set is as follows:

- Customer has “exactly | more | less” than X visits
- Customer first visit was “exactly | more | less” than X days
- Customer last visit was “exactly | more | less” than X days
- Customer provider is “facebook | twitter | email | any”

I am now trying to get my head around how I can build this into a query, I can’t even produce a tangible example! My hurdle seems to be checking the first record & the last record to make sure it meets the criteria.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68407/1

My Table:

```
|  id  | name           | email                                       | provider    | created_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | 1 | Mr Smith        | mr.smith@example.com         | facebook | 2018-11-01 09:00:00 | 
 | 2 | Mrs Smith      | mrs.smith@example.com      | facebook  | 2018-11-01 09:00:00 | 
 | 3 | Miss Smith     | miss.smith@example.com    | email        | 2018-11-01 09:00:00 | 
 | 4 | Doctor Smith | doctor.smith@example.com | email        | 2018-11-01 09:00:00 | 
 | 5 | Lord Smith    | lord.smith@example.com      | twitter      | 2018-11-01 09:00:00 | 
 | 6 | Lady Smith    | lady.smith@example.com      | email        | 2018-11-01 09:00:00 | 
 | 7 | Mr Smith        | mr.smith@example.com         | facebook | 2018-11-02 09:00:00 | 
 | 8 | Mrs Smith      | mrs.smith@example.com       | facebook  | 2018-11-02 09:00:00 | 
 | 9 | Doctor Smith | doctor.smith@example.com  | email        | 2018-11-02 09:00:00 | 
 | 10 | Lord Smith   | lord.smith@example.com       | twitter      | 2018-11-02 09:00:00 | 
 | 11 | Lady Smith   | lady.smith@example.com      | email        | 2018-11-02 09:00:00 | 
 | 12 | Mr Smith      | mr.smith@example.com         | facebook | 2018-11-03 09:00:00 | 
 | 13 | Mrs Smith    | mrs.smith@example.com       | facebook | 2018-11-03 09:00:00 | 
 | 14 | Miss Smith   | miss.smith@example.com     | email        | 2018-11-03 09:00:00 | 
 | 15 | Lord Smith   | ord.smith@example.com       | twitter      | 2018-11-03 09:00:00 | 
 | 16 | Lady Smith  | lady.smith@example.com      | email        | 2018-11-03 09:00:00 |
```

Example customer criteria for the query:

- Customer with more than 2 visits
- Customer first visit was more than 2 days ago
- Customer last visit was more than 1 day ago
- Customer provider is Facebook

Current query:

```
    $Customers = Customer::groupBy('email')
                 ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 2’)
                 ->where('created_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(2)->toDateTimeString())
                 ->get();
```

I can’t figure out how to pull the first customer record check that it more than 2 days old, and then pull their last record and make sure it is more than 1 day old.
I know that my current query is completely useless for what I am trying to achieve, but again I am struggling to pull this together.

Expected results:

```
|  id  | name           | email                                       | provider    | created_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | 12 | Mr Smith      | mr.smith@example.com         | facebook | 2018-11-03 09:00:00 | 
 | 13 | Mrs Smith    | mrs.smith@example.com       | facebook | 2018-11-03 09:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query in the MySQL dialect to make that selection is as follow

```
SELECT id, name, email, provider, created_at
FROM customers 
WHERE provider = 'facebook'
GROUP BY email
HAVING 
  count(*) > 2
  AND min(created_at) < date_sub(now(), interval 2 day)
  AND max(created_at) < date_sub(now(), interval 1 day)
```

That can be translated as an Eloquent query like so

```
$havingClause = 'count(*) > ? AND min(created_at) < ? AND max(created_at) < ?';
$havingClauseBindings = [
   2,
   Carbon::now()->subDays(2)->toDateTimeString(),
   Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->toDateTimeString()
];
$customers = Customer::where('provider', 'facebook')
                       ->groupBy('email')
                       ->havingRaw($havingClause, $havingClauseBindings)
                       ->get();
```

Comment: Ah, Min & Max, now I feel stupid! Accepting as answer as you added the Eloquent which is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The query you are looking for is:

```
select * from customers group by email having count(*) > 2 and min(created_at) <= '2018-10-02 09:00:00' and max(created_at) <= '2018-10-03 09:00:00' and provider = 'facebook'
```

assuming the current time is 2018-10-04 09:00:00.

In eloquent:

```
$Customers = Customer::groupBy('email')
             ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 2')
             ->havingRaw('max(created_at) < ?' , [Carbon::now()->subDays(2)->toDateTimeString()])
             ->havingRaw('min(created_at) < ?' , [Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->toDateTimeString()])
             ->havingRaw('provider = ?' , ['facebook'])
             ->get();
```

On a separate note, using eloquent you can chain methods, like the following

```
$customers = Customer::groupBy('email');

if( $includeCount ) {

     $customers->havingRaw('COUNT(*) > 2');
}
...
...
...
```